# Combinatorica and DualPartition function (for a Young diagram)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, physics, combinatorics, combinatorica

I am trying to understand how to evaluate the arm and leg functions of a Young tableaux using Mathematica. To do so I need the Combinatorica package. Then apparently the command

```
DualPartition[l_]:=Module[{i},Table[Length[Select[l,(#>=i)&]],{i,1,l[[1]]}]]
DualPartition[{}] = {};
```

will take as input a Young diagram and will output its dual. I understand that the original Young diagram is defined within the code I include above but due to my lack of experience with Mathematica **can you help me understand in detail this command above?**

What does the "Module" do and what is $i$ and what is $l$ counting there? And how can I see a specific example of a Young diagram to convince my self, say the Young diagram (2,1) [column, row].

Then the arm and leg functions are given by

```
get[Y_, i_]:=If[i > Length[Y ], 0, Y [[i]]]
arm[Y_, {i_, j_}]:=get[Y, i] − j
leg[Y_, {i_, j_}]:=get[DualPartition[Y ], j] − i
```

But I am not sure what "get" of the first line does. Any help with that would also be very useful.

Comment: There were quite some underscores missing in your code...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I did not copy it from a .nb file rather from a Latex one. But any comments on the actual question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Young tableaux, but from what I learned from the Combinatorica tutorial it looks like your `DualPartition` is not compatible with the Young tableaux generated in that package. Where did you get that definition of `DualPartition` from?

Comment: Hi! From here http://web.science.uu.nl/itf/Teaching/2013/R.J.Rodger.pdf page 71

Comment: Well, I've been looking at that document, but the definition just seems wrong. An example of a Young diagram would be `{{1, 3, 4, 5}, {2}}` (the second element of `Tableau[5]`. Then, after passing this to `DualPartition` `l[[1]]` would be {1, 3, 4, 5} and it would mean that the iterator `i` is supposed to run from 1 (a scalar) to {1, 3, 4, 5} (a vector). That's not possible so `l[[1]]` must be a scalar and the `l` must be a one-dimensional list and can't be a Young diagram as delivered by `Combinatorica`'s `Tableau`. I'm afraid you'll have to ask the author of the paper for an explanation.

Comment: Update: It occurred to me that what the author uses as input is not the fully enumerated Young tableaux that the `Tableaux` function yields but the 'blind' version that just counts the number of elements in a row. So, my example above, `{{1, 3, 4, 5}, {2}}` would be coded as `{4,1}` and `DualPartition` just works, generating `{2,1,1,1}` as it should.

Comment: With that established the code is rather straightforward and can be understand by visiting the various manual pages: [Module](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html), [Table](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html), [Length](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html), [Select](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html), [Slot or #](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html), [Function or &](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html))

Comment: It seems that the author of your paper only needs the Combinatorica package for the partitions function. In that case the whole package is unnecessary: You can use the built-in function `IntegerPartitions` for that. As an aside: You could define `DualPartitions` also as `DualPartition[p_List] :=  Length /@ Flatten[Table[1, {#}] & /@ p, {{2}, {1}}]` This is almost twice as fast and I find it more intuitive as it relates directly to the diagrams I showed in my answer below.

Comment: Hello! Ok, thanks a lot for your very detailed explanation and help. I will try to see now if I can make the code work with a few simple examples I know the answer already. I hope it is ok to come back here with a comment later on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Author of http://web.science.uu.nl/itf/Teaching/2013/R.J.Rodger.pdf uses the term "Young Diagram" to indicate a partition. Normally, the Young diagram is considered graphical a representation of a partition. If all boxes are filled with the concecutive integers 1 .. n, then it's called a (standard) Young Tableau. Rows and columns non-decreasing. If any integer is allowed (up to k) then we call it a Semi-Standard Young Tableau.

In the given context, the 'dual partition' is just the transpose partition. No Tableaux anywhere near.  TransposePartition[ ]  in `Combinatorica.

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to explain your `DualPartition` code as it does not seem to work on the Young tableaux generated by the Combinatorica package. Let's try to write something ourselves.

Assuming `DualPartition`calculates a conjugate tableau this could be written as follows:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
```

The `Tableau` function generates Young tableaux:

```
Tableaux[5]
(* {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 3, 4, 5}, {2}}, {{1, 2, 4, 5}, {3}}, 
   {{1, 2, 3, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5}}, {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4}}, 
   {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5}}, {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5}}, 
   {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 4, 5}, {2}, {3}}, {{1, 3, 5}, {2}, {4}}, 
   {{1, 2, 5}, {3}, {4}}, {{1, 3, 4}, {2}, {5}}, {{1, 2, 4}, {3}, {5}}, 
   {{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4}}, 
   {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}}, 
   {{1, 5}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, {{1, 4}, {2}, {3}, {5}}, 
   {{1, 3}, {2}, {4}, {5}}, {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}, 
   {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}} *)
```

Formatting it nicely:

```
 Multicolumn[
    Grid[#, Spacings -> {0, 0}] & /@ Map[Framed, Tableaux[5], {3}] 
     , 6, Appearance -> "Horizontal"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The conjugate form can be easily found with an uncommon variety of `Flatten` (see for instance this question)

```
Flatten[Tableaux[5], {{1}, {3}, {2}}]
```

with formatting:

```
 Multicolumn[
    Grid[#, Spacings -> {0, 0}] & /@ 
       Map[Framed, Flatten[Tableaux[5], {{1}, {3}, {2}}], {3}] 
     , 6, Appearance -> "Horizontal"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your nice answer. I have two questions though. 1) These diagrams have a redundancy I do not need. That is the boxes should be indistinguishable. How can I achieve this? For example the partition of 3 would have three diagrams if the boxes are indistinguishable while it would have 4 if we labeled them. 2) How can I calculate the arm and leg functions then? Thanks  lot.

Comment: As to 1) use `Tableaux[5] /. _Integer -> "" // Union` instead of `Tableaux[5]`. As to 2) that should be easy. Given the starting coordinate of the arm and the leg the arm can be picked right away. You may want to look up the functions `Part` and `Span`. The leg can be found in a similar way using the conjugate tableaux.

Comment: BTW I just noted that `Combinatorica` has a function `TransposeTableau` which does basically generate a dual.

Answer (score 2):

The function `Partitions[]` in `` Combinatorica` ``, which the author (Rodger) of http://web.science.uu.nl/itf/Teaching/2013/R.J.Rodger.pdf uses to create the Young diagrams, is now implemented as the `` System` `` function [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html).

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
Partitions[5]
(*  {{5}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}  *)

IntegerPartitions[5]
(*  {{5}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}  *)
```

The function `DualPartition` works on this representation of a Young diagram.

```
DualPartition[{2, 2, 1}]
(*  {3, 2}  *)
```

Note that there is another undocumented function `` Internal`IntegerPartitions[..] ``, which is equivalent to `Tally[IntegerPartitions[..]]`.  The advantage is that the equivalent of `DualPartition` also exists, `` Internal`TransposeIntegerPartition ``.

```
Internal`IntegerPartitions[5]
(*
  {{{5, 1}}, {{4, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {1, 2}},
   {{2, 2}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {1, 3}}, {{1, 5}}}
*)

Internal`TransposeIntegerPartition[Tally[{2, 2, 1}]]      (* Tally converts form *)
% /. {x_Integer, n_Integer} :> Sequence @@ Table[x, {n}]  (* Table etc. convert back *)
(*
  {{3, 1}, {2, 1}}
  {3, 2}
*)
```